# Equation over $\mathbb F_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

Given equation over $\mathbb F_2$: $$x_1x_2x_3+x_4x_5x_6=0$$

It has $50$ solutions. Let $N$ be set of solutions. If we give some linear dependencies to variables we will get cosets (linear subspace + a vector) that are inside 
$N$. For example $x_1=0,\  x_4+x_5=1$ will give coset of dimension $4$ that lies on $N$. I have checked using computer that there is not coset of dimension $4$ that is in $N$ and contains $111111$ vector. I need to prove it formally.

Any help for proving this or some books, articles about such problems will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that such a 4-dimensional vector space $V$ exists. Consider the 3-dimensional subspace $U\subset \Bbb{F}_2^6$ consisting of those vectors whose three first coordinates all vanish. Because $\dim V+\dim U=4+3>6$ these two subspaces intersect non-trivially. Thus there exists a non-zero vector $v$ of the form
$$
v=(0,0,0,v_4,v_5,v_6)\in V\cap U.
$$
Check what happens at the point $(1,1,1,1,1,1)+v$.

Comment: You may benefit from familiarizing with some concepts from coding theory. This kind of arguments combine combinatorics and linear algebra, and are all over the place in coding theory. If you tell more about your background (mathematician? programmer/engineer?) it may become easier to recommend a book.